# SSIS one source mapping to 2 tables with primary keys

Tags: ssis, edi

I am new to SSIS and I have to process a Cozyroc 835 EDI source into a database. One output of the EDI is a combination of 2 tables, Table A contains the foreign keys for table B so I have to insert into the tables in order.  I tried to use a multicast but it does not allow me to set precedence on table inserts. Is there any transformation that will allow me to dictate precedence?

Comment: Ummm, use arrows to dictate precedence?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer will be to have two Data Flow tasks and double process your file. Otherwise, I [have an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904915/181965) but seriously don't do it.

Just double process the file. The first time you will populate Table A, then you populate Table B so the FK relationship is satisfied.

From the comments - it was asked whether we could pass data out of a Data Flow Task.

Nope, data flows are self contained blocks of work. If you're concerned about the parsing, you could look at using a MultiCast component - one route to table A, one to Raw File Destination and then populate the raw file with only the columns you'll need to populate table B. Raw files are binary files unique to SSIS that it can read efficiently from as it doesn't require any locale aware parsing.

- [The Raw File Source and Destination](http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/04/the-raw-file-source-and-destination/)
- [Raw files are awesome](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-raw-files-are-awesome-131/)
- [Raw File Destination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141661.aspx)
- [Raw File Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140169.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I thought about that, I was concerned about overhead.  Is there anyway to pass the source from one data task to a control flow task to be used in a different data task or is it a all in type of thing?

Comment: Nope, data flows are self contained blocks of work. If you're concerned about the parsing, you could look at using a MultiCast component - one route to table A, one to Raw File Destination and then populate the raw file with only the columns you'll need to populate table B. Raw files are binary files unique to SSIS that it can read efficiently from as it doesn't require any locale aware parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I do not think I will be able to parse the EDI at as a batch, I need to be able to return the identity field and pass that to the service line data which is a one to many relationship.  I need to do this per transaction.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question then. Could you edit the original to help people understand the nuances of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is always to import the entire EDI into a single staging table, and then execute a stored proc that populates the two destination tables from the staging table.